# How can I make a Window became Identifiable in SwiftUI macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want be able to track which Window get focused by user there foe I am using `NSWindow.didBecomeMainNotification` and `NSWindow.didResignKeyNotification` which is doing good job, but the issue is here if my user decide to make a new window of my app via **File > New Window** my code would not be able to identify this 2 deferent Window, and all of windows would be recognised as the same one, here my used code:

```
@main
struct oioApp: App {
    
    let uuid: UUID = UUID()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWindow.didBecomeMainNotification), perform: { newValue in
                    print("Focused = true", uuid, newValue.hashValue)
                })
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWindow.didResignKeyNotification), perform: { newValue in
                    print("Focused = false", uuid, newValue.hashValue)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use a uuid for making it trackable or even using the hashValue of notification, but all my try did not worked, and I am receiving same print for both deferent Window.

Comment: Don't try to think in terms of AppKit, SwiftUI is different. Try reading about `focusedSceneValue` and `FocusedBinding`

Comment: Those topic are for Textfield for setting and reading focus not for window or any other view, i think the only way that can be solved is through swift not SwiftUI, SwiftUI is still so young and not mature enough to solving the issue via swiftui focused topic